# Docker image missing on Google Cloud Build "No such image", after being pushed and tagged

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

So we have a step which generates a docker image.

The next step uses the image to run a test, but by referring it using a LOCAL tag to avoid communicating with our remote registry (save time and traffic).

cloud build.yaml:

```
steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: bash
  args: ['./build_image.sh','$PROJECT_ID','base-image']

- name: 'base-image:latest'.  #This should ensure there's no need for an "actual" pull
  args: ['-f', './verify_image.ps1']
```

build_image.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

project=$1
applicationName=$2
version=1.0.3
image="gcr.io/$project/$applicationName:$version"
local_image="$applicationName:latest"

docker build -t $image .

echo "Tag image to make it locally availiable so we dont have to do a new pull"
docker tag $image $local_image

docker push $image

# docker run $local_image #works
```

This works most of the time on GCB. But every once in a while step 2 fails with:

```
Step #2: Already have image (with digest): base-image:latest
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "base-image:latest" failed: starting container: Error response from daemon: No such image: base-image@sha256:XXXX
```

I cen reproduce this by for ex starting 10 rebuilds of the same commit and then 0-5 of the rebuilds will throw this error.
We use this construct several places and makes our build process unstable.

GCB uses docker version:

> Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838

I have been searching high and low for an explanation to this error but without any luck.

Things I've tried:

- I have verified that both tags exists and that the digest's are
  correct in step 1 and step 2 for the base image. As you can se step 2
  confirms that the image with digest exists, but in the next line
  where I expect GCB to do a "docker run base-image:latest", for some
  reason, it does not, sometimes.
- I've tried doing a docker run using the local tag, in step 1 and it works (the image runs), but immediately after step 2 fails with the above message, claiming the image exists but does not.
- Tested with the official google builder docker image and the latest official docker image. Same result.

Every build on GCB, runs in its own vm host, so every step is a docker container running on the same vm. The docker daemon ,I believe is, hosted on the vm and not in the containers. This is why its possible to use the local tag and avoid the pull. But somehow state gets corrupted in the local registry/daemon or the local tag is not registered. Race condition?

In practice we use this setup so that the first step decides which version of the base-image to use in the second step (frameworks, etc) based on the content of the git repository being build, and then in the next step we can simply reference the local image as base-image:latest. This makes our build process more streamlined and enable us to do "dynamic" changes without bothering other devs on purpose.
We have a lot of products using a very small number of frameworks the similar way, so this makes good sense.

If anyone has any suggestions how to resolve/fix/workaround this issue please help :).

Kind regards
Christian

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to assume that step 2 is executed in the same environment that step 1, and to link steps with local artifacts (here, your local Docker image). Why don't you push the image (`latest` in your case) to a container registry, and let step 2 pull the image if needed? I've understood that this is for saving time and traffic but is it worth the case? Could you try to push `latest` in step 1 and see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: Hi norbjd, according to the documentation I con find on GCB all containers are run on the same host and share /workspace. So there should be no issue in that regard. To elaborate on the reason why we are doing this it is actually because we use step 2 to decide which version to use in the next step. This is done to have an identical build process for a range of our products. So it makes good sense to decide which version to use, cache it as the latest locally and reference it like that. I will edit my post to remove the assumption part. Anyway I still think this look like a timing issue /bug.

Comment: It should have said:   we use step 1 to decide, not 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

To use cached images in your builds you must use `--cache-from` flag when you build your images like in:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [
            'build',
            '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[IMAGE_NAME]:latest',
            '--cache-from', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[IMAGE_NAME]:latest',
            '.'
        ]
```

more on this can be [found here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds).

Comment: Hi, thank you, unfortunately we're not using it for building new images. We are executing/running the image in the next step, not building a new one :).

Comment: hey @ChristianMikkelsen , I'm working in Google Cloud Platform support and there were same reports like your issue. However, a fix for the issue has been rolled out and it should effective right now. Can you confirm that you still face this issue. if you so, I would like to direct to [open a support ticket following this](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/role-based-support#case_management), if you have support package. if not, you will be able to [create public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) issue and it will be handle by a support engineer.

Comment: Hi Methkal, I've done some stress testing the last few days and it does appear to have been resolved :-D. I'll give it a couple of more days, but I think we in the clear :)